# JQUERY: Looping and adding properties for dynamic selector

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

I got new problem here!

```
    var name=prompt("Populate Fields");
var array = $(name.split(","));
$.each(array,function(i){
    $('input[name="'+ array[i] + '"]').prop=('checked', 'checked');
    alert(array[i]);
    });
alert("Done");
    }
```

Ok where is the problem?
My goal is - i wrote in popup - banana, dog, wife and LOOP should add propertie for each of array entries.

Like if i write:

```
$('input[name="dog"]').prop('checked','yes');
```

Everything works well, checkbox gets checked, but when i do it in loop, nothing works, but if i try to special put some **' " '** there in prompt, then Console Log crashes, so it means it passes correct name there, because alert pops every entry what i write there.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If there is an event handler attached to this element,since it is dynamically added to the page you need to delegate.Try this:

```
$('body').on(event, 'input[name="dog"]', function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
})
```

Comment: Everything is working well with [name="manual input"], but if i make "manual input" as '+ array [i]+' then it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm such ADHD or I'm so careful!
Take a look around

On first code after **.prop** i've had **=**